# 'GooglePlaceModule' imported by the module 'AppModule' app returning blank screen as a result

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ng-modules

Receiving the following error:

```
main.ts:19 Error: Unexpected value 'GooglePlaceModule'
imported by the module 'AppModule'. 
Please add an @NgModule annotation.  at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (core.mjs:23575:19)     
at core.mjs:23586:9     
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)     
at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (core.mjs:23584:60)     
at AppModule.get (core.mjs:23537:21)     
at getInjectorDef (core.mjs:506:13)     
at walkProviderTree (core.mjs:8227:18)     
at core.mjs:8187:13     
at core.mjs:4404:76     
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

As a result on my local host application I am returning a blank page

Strangely when I click into `'ngx-google-places-autocomplete'` in npm modules `ngx-google-places-autocomplete.module` is an empty class

In app.module I am getting the following errors:

```
ngx-google-places-autocomplete.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ngx-google-places-autocomplete) which declares GooglePlaceModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
'NgxCurrencyModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
currency-mask.module.d.ts(2, 60): This likely means that the library (ngx-currency) which declares NgxCurrencyModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.(
```

Setup:

```
Angular CLI: 15.0.4
Node: 18.15.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: darwin arm64

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1500.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.0.4
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.6
@angular/cdk                    15.0.3
@angular/fire                   7.5.0
@angular/material               15.0.3
@schematics/angular             14.2.6
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

Currently using ionic framework with angular for an application

1. I have tried recloning my application and this issue occurs only on my device, not on any of my team members
2. I have deleted and reinstalled npm packages
3. Cleared space in device hard drive

I am trying to resolve the blank screen in the application

Comment: as short term solution I have updated my angular.json file so that any mention of `aot: boolean` is to `false`

I still do not know the root cause however and would appreciate assistance